# Array is not recognized in Codeigniter's View

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to pass an array to a view from a controller but I can't and I don't know why.

I have a model, a controller and a view.

The model:

```
<?php

class Modelo_bd extends CI_Model
{
    public function datos()
    {
        $cnb=$this->db->query("SELECT * from anuncios");
        return $cnb->result();  
    }
} 

?>
```

The controller:

```
if($this->modelo_usuarios->puede_entrar($usr)) 
{
   $this->load->model("modelo_bd");
   $cbd=$this->modelo_bd->datos();
   $this->load->view('datos',$cbd);

   return true;
}
```

The view:

```
<?php
echo $cbd->titulo_a;
echo $cbd->contenido;
?>
```

The error is in the view.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: cbd

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Why $cbd variable isn't recognized in the view if it is an array? How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you rather do:

**The controller:**

```
if($this->modelo_usuarios->puede_entrar($usr)) 
{
   $this->load->model("modelo_bd");
   $data['cbd']=$this->modelo_bd->datos();
   $this->load->view('datos',$data);

       return true;
}
```

**The view:**

```
<?php
   foreach($cbd as $key => $row){
   echo $row->titulo_a;
   echo $row->contenido;
}

?>
```

I think this works better, your choice.

Comment: Yes. Now it runs. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Thanks, glad to know I could help

Answer (score 1):

In the **controller** :

```
if($this->modelo_usuarios->puede_entrar($usr)) 
{
   $this->load->model("modelo_bd");
   $cbd=$this->modelo_bd->datos();
   $this->load->view('datos', array('cbd' => $cbd);       
   return true;
}
```

The second parameter should be array.

You can use in the model:

```
public function datos()
{
    return $this->db->query("SELECT * from anuncios");
}
```

and in the view:

```
<?php
foreach ($cdb->result() as $item) {
  echo $item->titulo_a;
  echo $item->contenido;
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes. It works if I type echo $cbd[0]->titulo_a echo $cbd[0]->contenido. But if I use a foreach like: foreach ($cbd->result() as $f) { echo $f->titulo_a; echo $f->contenido; } there is an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object. How can I fix this one?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this

```
if($this->modelo_usuarios->puede_entrar($usr)) 
{
   $this->load->model("modelo_bd");
   $data['cbd'] =   $this->modelo_bd->datos();
   $this->load->view('datos',$data);
}
```